# The structure of a family of k- subsets of a n-set

Tags: combinatorics

Call a set a $n$-set if its number of elements is $n$. Let $F=\{A_1,A_2,...,A_m\}$ be a family of $k$-subsets of a $n$-set. Suppose $F$ has additionally the following property:

If $A_i$ is any element of $F$ and if $B$ is any $k-1$-subset of $A_i$ then there exists an $A_j$ different from $A_i$ (depending on $B$) in $F$ s.t. $B$ is a subset of $A_j$.

Question: Can we characterize the structure of sets $F$? Of course the set of all $k$ subsets of an $m$-set with  $k< m\leq n$  has the property above. But are there any other family of subsets with this property?

Comment: There are other examples of such families, yes. You can simply write down some, taking for example $n = 4$ and $k=2$ there is a family of size $4$.

Comment: Thanks https://math.stackexchange.com/users/379594/dirk-liebhold